# Отображение html страницы в юнити игре

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно отобразить html страницу с сайта в UIView в игре.

Нашол на офф сайте такой вариант:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
    }
}
```

Но это картинка а мне нужно страница с текстом... подскажите как решить проблему.

Comment: вам нужен текст или полноценная html страница?

Comment: если нужно отображение веб страницы в Unity, то на это есть уже миллион готовых решений, например https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32461

Comment: одно из 2-х, на странице правила написаны для игры, нужно их загрузить с сайта

Comment: конечно 20$ это не много но хотелось бы повышать свой уровень

Comment: @Abs3akt если повышать уровень, то читаете документацию по `WebView` в андроид. `UIWebView` на iOS что вам ещё там надо? Для десктопов тоже есть. Потом пишите реализацию на нативе для каждой платформы и оборачиваете через `ifdef`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил пойти простым путём, так как страницу с текстом в формате html не получилось отобразить, нашол решение для файла `.txt`

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Net;

public Text textView;

    public void Start(){

            string fileContent = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.yoursite.com/namefile.txt");

            GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle ();
            style.richText = true;
            textView.text = fileContent;
    }
}
```

В Unity3D есть **Rich Text** о существований которого я не знал, на случай если кому ещё понадобится вот док. с офф. сайта [Unity Rich Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html)